# Arquillian unsatisfied dependency in picketlink

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss-arquillian, picketlink

I have application with PicketLink included as maven dependency. I have written arquillian test case that does not involve PicketLink in any way, but test is failing because of CDI in picketlink.

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class WebServiceTest {

    @Deployment
    public static WebArchive deployment() {     
        return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.war")
                .addAsManifestResource(new File("test/beans.xml"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testMath() {
        Assert.assertEquals(2, 1+1);
    }
}
```

When I run JUnit test, i get this error:

```
Unsatisfied dependencies for type [DefaultLoginCredentials] with qualifiers [@Default] 
at injection point [[field] @Inject private org.picketlink.internal.AbstractIdentity.loginCredential]
```

Which is wierd, considering I'm not including picketlink into WebArchive at all. I tought arquillian should isolate test case from the rest of my application. Moreover, I'm excluding picketlink in beans.xml that I'm including into WebArchive:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
    version="1.1" bean-discovery-mode="all">

    <scan>
        <exclude name="org.picketlink.**" />
    </scan>
</beans>
```

Similar problem was also [reported on developer.jboss](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/250422), but without any resolution. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing weld dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.CR3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
    <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.5.Final</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

with managed wildfly

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
    <version>${wildfly.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

resolved my issue. Note that you have to add `JBOSS_HOME` env. variable, when using managed wildfly. Environment variable can be added in IDE altering running configuration.